# How to upload a file into a repo?

Tags: github

I have a free version github account where I created a repo and I need to add a 670KB text file (it has test data) into this repo. I use IE browser and Windows XP OS, and haven't downloaded or installed any gihub software or app into my local system.

How do you directly upload the file into the repo without creating a file and then copying the content?

Comment: go through the git tutorial: http://learn.github.com/p/intro.html

Comment: This is not explained in help. I am not asking hoe to create a new file, it can be done by clicking '+' against repo name. What am I asking is how to directly upload an existing file from local system into git if you don't have git installed. I think the below answer by alestanis seems right, one needs to have git installed. :(

Comment: you can always do what alestanis suggested and then copy/paste the text into github

Answer (score 0):

Github is supposed to be used wit git, a version control system. You need to use git in order to download/upload/update files inside a github repo.

You can also create a file directly inside Github by clicking on the little button on the right of your repo's name:

[image: Create file in guthub]

And then you can modify it inside Github by clicking on it.